# Intersection between density plots of multiple groups

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I'm using `ggplot` / `easyGgplot2` to create density plots of two groups. I would like have a metric or indication of how much intersection there is between the two curves.  I might even use any other solution without the curves, as long as it allows me to have a measure of which groups are more distinct (of several different groups of data).

Is there any easy way to do this in R?

For example using this sample, which generates this plot

[image]

How can I estimate the percentage of area that is common to both?

```
ggplot2.density(data=weight, xName='weight', groupName='sex',
    legendPosition="top",
    alpha=0.5, fillGroupDensity=TRUE )
```

Comment: If you are interested in group differences of some measure (in the linked image, it would be `weight`), then why not just do a t-test?

Comment: It seems like you might want to consult a statistician rather than a programmer here depending on your data needs. If your question is about finding a statistically appropriate tests or estimation method, then you should be asking over at [stats.se]. If you know what test you want to perform but don't know how to do it in R, then you should edit your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the previous answer, but this may be a bit more intuitive, also I made sure to use a common bandwidth:

```
library ( "caTools" )

# Extract common bandwidth
Bw <- ( density ( iris$Petal.Width ))$bw

# Get iris data
Sample <- with ( iris, split ( Petal.Width, Species ))[ 2:3 ]

# Estimate kernel densities using common bandwidth
Densities <- lapply ( Sample, density,
                      bw = bw,
                      n = 512,
                      from = -1,
                      to = 3 )

# Plot
plot( Densities [[ 1 ]], xlim = c ( -1, 3 ),
      col = "steelblue",
      main = "" )
lines ( Densities [[ 2 ]], col = "orange" )

# Overlap
X <- Densities [[ 1 ]]$x
Y1 <- Densities [[ 1 ]]$y
Y2 <- Densities [[ 2 ]]$y

Overlap <- pmin ( Y1, Y2 )
polygon ( c ( X, X [ 1 ]), c ( Overlap, Overlap [ 1 ]),
    lwd = 2, col = "hotpink", border = "n", density = 20) 

# Integrate
Total <- trapz ( X, Y1 ) + trapz ( X, Y2 )
(Surface <- trapz ( X, Overlap ) / Total)
SText <- paste ( sprintf ( "%.3f", 100*Surface ), "%" )
text ( X [ which.max ( Overlap )], 1.2 * max ( Overlap ), SText )
```

[image: Overlap of densities of versicolor and virginica petal widths]

Comment: nice answer+1, `pmin` is much simpler of course! and `trapz` is a cool function.  Not sure why the bandwidths need to be the same though?

Comment: Thanks! Just one remark, shouldn't I multiply the intersection area by 2 to get the correct ratio?
For instance, if I have two exactly equal PDFs, it should give 100%. Still, dividing the area of the intersection by the sum of each PDF area will only get me only 50%. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6):

First, make some data to use.  Here, we will look at the Petal Width of two plant species from the built-in `iris` dataset.

```
## Some sample data from iris
dat <- droplevels(with(iris, iris[Species %in% c("versicolor", "virginica"), ]))

## make a similar graph
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(Petal.Width, fill=Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

To find the area of the intersection, you can use `approxfun` to approximate the function describing the overlap.  Then, integrate it the get the area.  Since these are density curves, their area is 1 (ish) so the integral will be the percentage overlap.

```
## Get density curves for each species
ps <- lapply(split(dat, dat$Species), function(x) {
    dens <- density(x$Petal.Width)
    data.frame(x=dens$x, y=dens$y)
})

## Approximate the functions and find intersection
fs <- sapply(ps, function(x) approxfun(x$x, x$y, yleft=0, yright=0))
f <- function(x) fs[[1]](x) - fs[[2]](x)   # function to minimize (difference b/w curves)
meet <- uniroot(f, interval=c(1, 2))$root  # intersection of the two curves

## Find overlapping x, y values
ps1 <- is.na(cut(ps[[1]]$x, c(-Inf, meet)))
ps2 <- is.na(cut(ps[[2]]$x, c(Inf, meet)))
shared <- rbind(ps[[1]][ps1,], ps[[2]][ps2,])

## Approximate function of intersection
f <- with(shared, approxfun(x, y, yleft=0, yright=0))

## have a look
xs <- seq(0, 3, len=1000)
plot(xs, f(xs), type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0, 2))

points(ps[[1]], col="red", type="l", lty=2, lwd=2)
points(ps[[2]], col="blue", type="l", lty=2, lwd=2)

polygon(c(xs, rev(xs)), y=c(f(xs), rep(0, length(xs))), col="orange", density=40)
```

[image]

```
## Integrate it to get the value
integrate(f, lower=0, upper=3)$value
# [1] 0.1548127
```